# How to hook up three monitors with my motherboard?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Use 3 Monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/145009/how-to-use-3-monitors)

The motherboard that I'm using is an AsusTek M3A (details [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2Plus/M3A)) and the video card I have is an ATI radeon 3870.  The problem is that the video card only has two DVI slots.  What would be the easiest way to get triple monitors going?  I could install another video card but the motherboard only has one PCI express x16 slot (which is used by the ATI card). Would an old PCI 2.2 video card work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use 3 Monitors](http://superuser.com/questions/145009/how-to-use-3-monitors) or [Three monitors setup on machine with integrated graphic card](http://superuser.com/questions/24376/three-monitors-setup-on-machine-with-integrated-graphic-card) or [How can I set Windows 7 up to use three monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/260634/how-can-i-set-windows-7-up-to-use-three-monitors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BIOS on my motherboard still gives an option to initialize the PEG (PCI Express Graphics) or PCI slot first, so I would assume a PCI 2.2 card should work.

If it doesn't work, you could certainly use a [USB-to-DVI](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=usb%20dvi%20adapter&x=0&y=0) or USB-to-VGA adapter.

I do remember running into compatibility issues with some really old PCI video cards in a multi-monitor setup back when AGP was all the rage, but if you already have a card it wouldn't hurt to try.